# vb.net Specified Select query OLEDB database

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, oledb, oledbcommand

Please help, im trying to show the specified data on datagridview with SELECT,FROM,WHERE clause:

```
Private Sub showdata()
    Dim identity As String = frmmgrusers.hdtxtid.Text
    Dim dbcommand As String
    dbcommand = "SELECT First_Name, Second_Name, Dob, ID_Card_No, Email, Username, [Password] FROM UsersTB WHERE ID='" & identity & "'"
    adt = New OleDbDataAdapter(dbcommand, dbconn)
    datatable = New DataTable
    adt.Fill(datatable)
    dgvusersreporting.DataSource = datatable
End Sub
```

But it shows nothing, This showdata() sub is written on a form load when users click a button from other form it will show a form with datagridview showed the specified data with ID. I tried to remove the WHERE clause:

dbcommand = "SELECT First_Name, Second_Name, Dob, ID_Card_No, Email, Username, [Password] FROM UsersTB"

And it show the data (weird...?) but i need only the specified data with ID

Comment: Not weird.  If there is no record with that ID nothing will show.  You should use parameters always rather than glue strings together for a query.  And passwords should never be stored as plain text

Comment: I think i forgot i need to include ID on Select but i tried that still nothing appear Also ID has a record of Autonumber 1,2,... on other form in frmgrusers.hdtxtid has a 1,2 text inside it is because of clicking datagridview selected cell so when i clicked a cell on datagridview from frmgrusers it fills the hdtxtid and clicked the show button which will show another form with datagridview with "SELECT First_Name, Second_Name, Dob, ID_Card_No, Email, Username, [Password] FROM UsersTB WHERE ID='" & identity & "'" query

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it actually works... by this query "SELECT First_Name, Second_Name, Dob, ID_Card_No, Email, Username, [Password] FROM UsersTB where ID=" & identity & " " though didn't understand whats the difference of ID='" & 
identity & "' to ID=" $ identity $ " "